# Excel Formula Error - IFERROR AND SEARCH FUNCTION

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can someone explain the mistake in the below formula??

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH({"Request for Admin","Request for Info"},A2),"FALSE"),"Yes","No")
```

I need correction only with above format.... If any new format also, I should recheck....

Comment: Is it possible to simplify: "Request*" instead of {"Request for Admin", "Request for Info"}

Comment: What error do you get? Do no enclose `FALSE` with double quote. So, try `=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH({"Request for Admin", "Request for Info"},A2),FALSE),"Yes","No")`

Comment: No I cann't simplify to "Request*" because there is a "Request for change" which i should use for another column. The formula i used was  =IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Request",A2),"FALSE"),"Yes","No") and it worked good. Cell A2 can be empty... Now when i use multiple search it is giving #SPILL! error... Please help

Comment: @KannanPrince Do you want `Yes` if one of you search item it match?

Comment: Yes... Cell A2 can be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your actual goal. If you want result `Yes` when one of your search item match to `A2` cell then could try-

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Request for Admin","Request for Info"},A2))),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harun... I tried the above formula and it works... Could you please help me understand why ISNUMBER is used???

Comment: @KannanPrince if you separate the functions, you will see search() will give a numerical result if it finds the target and an error if not. OR() and ISNUMBER() deal with that. Testing this sort of thing will help you understand.